# how to remap random test labels 0 to 9 to 1 to 10?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I am using np.random.choice(num_test_images, 5) to randomly select 5 images from an array of test data.
every time, it gives me a random combination of 5 labels as an array of shape (5,1).

for example, I can get a 5 label array like this:

```
## below I am reproducing two of my random  arrays.
# 
random_test_labels= np.ndarray((5,1), buffer=np.array([0,7,2,4,2]), dtype=int)

random_test_labels
array([[0],
       [7],
       [2],
       [4],
       [2]], dtype=int)


#or, like this.
random_test_labels= np.ndarray((5,1), buffer=np.array([7,5,1,0,1]), dtype=int)
random_test_labels
array([[7],
       [5],
       [1],
       [0],
       [1]])
```

I want to rename the labels 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

so I am trying to use a dictionary,
map_dict = {0:1,1:2,3:4,5:6,6:7,7:8,8:9,9:10}

however, this method does not work:

```
map_dict = {0:1,1:2,3:4,5:6,6:7,7:8,8:9,9:10}

random_test_labels1 = random_test_labels

for k, v in map_dict.items():
    random_test_labels1[random_test_labels1 == k] = v

random_test_labels1  # this output is wrong
array([[ 2],
       [10],
       [ 2],
       [ 4],
       [ 2]])
```

as it does not give me the expected result,
random_test_labels1 as

```
array([[1],
       [8],
       [3],
       [5],
       [3]])
```

for the original array,  np.array([0,7,2,4,2]).  any help please?

Comment: First of all, just do array +=1, numpy will automatically add 1 to all values in the array. Regarding your approach: You assign values multiple times, aka when mapping a 1 to a 2 you will change it to a 3 in the next iteration. (Note that the order in which the dictionary returns the values will change the results)

Comment: thank you, it is really very easy. I love stackoverflow for people like you!